# Erysipelas vs cellulitis vs paronychia

Tags: infection, terminology, fingers

According to Wikipedia:

- "Erysipelas is a relatively common bacterial infection of the superficial layer of the skin."[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erysipelas)
- "Cellulitis is a bacterial infection involving the inner layers of the skin."[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulitis)
- "Paronychia is an inflammation of the skin around the nail."[(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronychia)

I can understand the distinction made between erysipelas and cellulitis. However, I do not get why the term "paronychia" has been introduced. Given the previous definitions, paronychia could have been named "finger erysipelas" or "finger cellulitis". By the way, I am not aware of any other anatomical location where skin infections get such a specific name.
**What is, therefore, the motivation of using the term "paronychia" in place of "erysipelas" or "cellulitis" ?**
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Paronychia could be seen as an umbrella term for any inflammation around the nails of fingers or toes. Cellulitis being one kind.

The umbrella term is referring to the anatomical region as it is

> Latin, from Greek [παρωνυχία] paronykhia "whitlow," from [para- "beside" (see para- (1)) + onyx "nail" (see nail (n.)) + abstract noun ending -ia.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/paronychia)

See [this Wikipedia section](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronychia#Differential) for differential (more specific) diagnoses of paronychia.

You said:

> I am not aware of any other anatomical location where skin infections get such a specific name.

Many names for inflammatory conditions come from the place on the body [and have the suffix *-itis* meaning inflammation](https://globalrph.com/medical-terms-introduction/). You already mentioned cellulitis. There are also, for example:

- Conjunctivitis (also known as pink eye) is inflammation of the conjunctiva ([outer layer of the white of the eye](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK519502/)). It also affects the inner surface of eyelids? That's an inflammation.
- Gingivitis which is inflammation of the gingiva ([the gums](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/gingiva))